# Spring Security without Spring Tag Library (JSTL)

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security

We are having a typical web application which uses Spring Security and JSPs. We use standard Spring Security tag library to show/hide, allow/restrict parts of the web pages based of user roles.

Now we are going to change the JSP part and write a complete Javascript based client.

1. Is there a way to get a similar functionality provided by the tag library with Javascript.
2. If not, what are the things we should be worry about in implementing our own mechanism in Javascript.

Thanks,
Ish

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "does Spring Security have a Javascript equivalent to the JSP tags" then the answer is definitely "no". The obvious difference is that Javascript runs on the client whereas JSP is executed on the server, so you can't just rely on hiding sensitive information using a Javascript library as this would be insecure.

A Javascript client is fundamentally different and the security will most likely be implemented in the API you expose to it to allow it to retrieve data from the server. It will consist of security contstraints applied to URLs and server-side methods, rather than having anything to do with a display technology, so in some ways it is simpler to test and reason about than JSP security, since it is decoupled from the actual display code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if I have a menu called 'administration' item in my application is it accessible only for Server Admins, I should show it to every users and display a message saying "You are not Allowed" after the request hits the server side, if he/she is not an admin.

Comment: No, I'd say you'd only show the item to people who have the admin role. If you're using a REST-like API, then the menu would probably be the result of a request to the server, and the links you return would be dependent on the user's role.